# how I could use math expression in svg file?

Tags: svg

for example for this circle
how I could use a math expression  like this "100*2"

```
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" transform="translate("100*2" 300)" />
```

Comment: javascript is one way or any other dynamic web language

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Why can't you just type in `200` instead of `100*2`? Are you actually trying to insert the value of a variable into an SVG drawing? If so, what language are you using? As it stands, this question should be closed (too broad / unclear what you're asking).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I'm going to guess the '2' represents the variable he is trying to compute the expression `100*x` with.

Comment: Typing in `200` instead of `100*2` is easy, and there's no point to it. But for an expression more like `(1+sqrt(5))/2`, I can see more reason to wish for expression processing. But since this question is the most relevant to the idea, my guess is that no such feature exists.

Comment: My motivation for this is reason why 200 is 200. When you type 4.188 you have end result and number without meaning. Typing (2/3)*(2*3.1415926) I know that is 2/3 of full circle.

Comment: set pathLength="300" then 2/3 of the circle is 100